# How to implement array slicing for Expression within SelectQuery in peewee?

Tags: python, peewee

Is it possible to implement array slicing for Expression within SelectQuery in peewee?

I want to use pattern matching in PostgreSQL query with regexp, and I can do it with `fn.REGEXP_MATCH(col_name, regexp)` but it returns array as string like so `"['foo']"`. So I need to get only first element of array with slice on the DB side like so: `(regexp_match(col_name, regexp)[1]`.

I need to implement this query with orm:

```
SELECT (regexp_match(h.name, '^ATM-\w{5}-(\S+)$'))[1] FROM zbxhost h;
```

And this try returns me array as string:

```
ZbxHost.select(ZbxHost.name, fn.REGEXP_MATCH(ZbxHost.name, '^ATM-\w{5}-(\S+)$'))
```

The only thing that comes to my mind is not to use regexp. And in this case it's possible, but what if it will be necessary in future?

Comment: Do you mean you are getting like '["foo1"], ["foo2"]' but you wanted to get [ ["foo1"],["foo2"] ] ?

Comment: I want to get just first value from each array: just 'foo1' instead of "['foo1']" or '["foo1"], ["foo2"]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using the "unnest" function (via fn.unnest).

If you're looking for implementing array-type stuff, check out the implementation of ArrayField in playhouse/postgres_ext.py:

https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/b48aab31fe5cd788099b821b2c2cf5d05d196d3f/playhouse/postgres_ext.py#L114-L184

Comment: It's strange, but I tried to use unnest function before post this question and something went wrong, but now it works)) 
Apparently, I had mistake in my code...

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot for your reply and so cool ORM!
I read ArrayField API before asking the question and tried to understand how you implement slicing there, but it was to difficult for me yesterday.